# How to click selenium submenus with python

Tags: python, selenium, click

I'm trying to make this code below to download the chart information
but I'm not able

```
#Biblioteca 
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# configurações para abrir o navegador chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# a execução do Selenium no chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

# acessando o site SRT
driver.get('https://www.bcb.gov.br/estatisticas/detalhamentoGrafico/graficosspb/MeiosPagamentosValortrimestralConsolidado')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("highcharts-no-tooltip highcharts-button highcharts-contextbutton highcharts-button-normal")

for element in elements:
  element.click()
  baixar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-w74uab8-1922"]/div/ul/li[7]')
  baixar.click()
```

need to make this click

[image]

Baixar arquivo CSV

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you could run without `--headless` to see what browser is doing, And you can still use browser to check xpath, etc.

Comment: it seems it load similar values as JSON from https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/servico/sitebcb/spb_meios_pagamentos_dados_trimestrais  and may be simpler to download this JSON and convert to CSV in Python. Probably it may works even without Selenium - so it may work faster.